# How to plot many lines from data in Excel in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm kinda new to R, is there any way to plot ColA as X-axes, ColB as y-axis, ColC as X-axis and ColD as the y-axis and so on. And all the paired cols have same name (e.g., ColA=Dis and Colb = hard, ColC=Dis and COLd= hard and so on).
 Basically what I have done is that I have merged all the Dis and hard from different sheets in different excels into one datasheet, then I thought I could plot it with excel, however, the excel can only display 255 curves in one figure, which I probably have one thousand curves. Then my dataset looks like this:

---

A     B   C    D   E    F    G   H ...

---

Dis hard Dis hard Dis hard Dis hard ...

---

1    3    4   6   9    11   15  20

---

3    4    6    9  11   22   25   30

---

and so on
I have tried the following code:

```
nwb1<-read.xlsx("newresult.xlsx")
nwb1<-as.data.frame(nwb1)
ggplot(data=nwb1, aes(x=displacement, y=hardness)) + geom_line() + geom_point( size=4, shape=21, fill="white")
```

the error message told me that "data` must be uniquely named but has duplicate columns"

Comment: In general, it is ideal to ask a question once you have tried something. Have you searched the internet for a way to do this in R, and if so, what did you find?

Comment: I have tried directly use the ggplot2 and the error massages turn out that "data` must be uniquely named but has duplicate columns " should i change the names of the cols? since i have like 2000 cols data, it's kind of redundant to do that.

Comment: Could you edit your question to show the code/work that you are doing? (A code formatting tool is available in the editor.) It would be much easier for people to help you with something that does not work, rather than writing new code from scratch for you.

Comment: hey, so you have duplicated column names. Did you rename them to Dis and hard?

Comment: li yucheng, perhaps this is two problems: (1) read a "xlsx" file, dealing with duplicate column names; and (2) how to plot data where every other row should go on the x-axis, etc. The two are relatively unrelated.

Comment: actually I extracted them from many xlsx files into newresult.xlsx, and in these files they are named as Dis and hard.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try something like this, I do not have your data, so for illustration purpose, I make 3 excel files first, each having a column call Dis and another call hard:

```
library(openxlsx)
for(i in 1:3){
df = data.frame(Dis=1:10,hard=rpois(10,i)) 
write.xlsx(df,file=paste("file",i,".xlsx",sep=""))
}
```

Now we start with making a vector of all the excel files you want to plot:

```
fl = c("file1.xlsx","file2.xlsx","file3.xlsx")
df = lapply(fl,function(i){
x = read.xlsx(i)
x$sample=sub(".xlsx","",i)
x
})

df = do.call(rbind,df)
head(df)
  Dis hard sample
1   1    1  file1
2   2    0  file1
3   3    0  file1
4   4    2  file1
5   5    2  file1
6   6    2  file1
```

The dataframe df is concatenated from all your excel files and has an extra column call sample to denote the file where it came from. You can also make a table like this in excel if you have more problems reading / combining files. Once you have something like that, we plot:

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Dis, y=hard,col=sample)) + geom_line() + 
geom_point( size=4, shape=21, fill="white")
```

[image]

In the event you have merged your data with excel, you will read in a very odd data.frame, and you can try the following, **not recommended** :

```
values = do.call(cbind,lapply(1:5,function(i)cbind(1:10,1:10+rnorm(10))))
df = data.frame(rbind(rep(c("Dis","hard"),5),values))
colnames(df)=LETTERS[1:10]
head(df)
    A                B   C                 D   E                 F   G
1 Dis             hard Dis              hard Dis              hard Dis
2   1 1.09836250501178   1 0.350206285061174   1 0.620196066920137   1
3   2 1.81400395465058   2   4.2990376623795   2  1.00810320999903   2
4   3 3.94001753647332   3  3.32736042411927   3  3.23285030270875   3
5   4 3.93795305230344   4  4.14948397718842   4  3.88849871990867   4
6   5 5.08952019766558   5  5.18257115670042   5  4.72275692563252   5
                 H   I                J
1             hard Dis             hard
2 1.08603311982134   1 0.51876628213101
3 1.38614529438877   2 1.73020370187464
4 2.70650988128661   3 4.65143843701136
5 3.26676976653313   4 5.17606099966858
6 5.00453246607507   5 6.72671659884557

newdf = data.frame(
Dis=as.numeric(unlist(lapply(df[-1,df[1,] == "Dis"],as.character))),
hard=as.numeric(unlist(lapply(df[-1,df[1,] == "hard"],as.character))),
group = rep(1:(ncol(df)/2),each=nrow(df)-1)
)
ggplot(newdf,aes(x=Dis,y=hard,group=group))+geom_line()
```

Comment: I have merged all the Dis and hard from different sheets in different excels into one datasheet. The Dis and hard are repeated in one datasheet. Do you know how that may be plotted

Comment: @liyucheng, it's do-able, but how do you plan to visualize all 1000 curves in one plot? like how do you know which is from which

Comment: It's like all the curves show a converging trend, and i just want to show the general trend rather than which is from which

Comment: I suggest using the code above to merge the datasets and plot.. you do not use "col=..", otherwise your data is very hard to handle